# uk.co.logtailer.jmeter.protocol.mq.sampler.MQSampler in JMeter script

Tags: jmeter

JMeter crashes while trying to load a .JMX script giving error "Empty TestPlan - see log file". I did my research around and found that the possible solutions/issues can be:

1) Moving up/down Java versions on your machine.

2) Some JAR is missing in the lib/ext folder of JMeter.

The issue seems to be the latter, as I can see the following line in the JMX script:

```
<uk.co.logtailer.jmeter.protocol.mq.sampler.MQSampler guiclass="uk.co.logtailer.jmeter.protocol.mq.control.gui.MQSamplerGui" testclass="uk.co.logtailer.jmeter.protocol.mq.sampler.MQSampler" testname="MQSampler" enabled="false">
```

I am not able to find the JAR which can support this MQ Sampler. I have tried a few from ActiveMQ but they didn't work.

I will appreciate if someone can help me with the JAR or point out if my understanding of the issue is wrong.

Log shows:

```
2014/09/04 10:36:12 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: uk.co.logtailer.jmeter.protocol.mq.sampler.MQSampler : uk.co.logtailer.jmeter.protocol.mq.sampler.MQSampler
---- Debugging information ----
message             : uk.co.logtailer.jmeter.protocol.mq.sampler.MQSampler
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : uk.co.logtailer.jmeter.protocol.mq.sampler.MQSampler
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[4]/uk.co.logtailer.jmeter.protocol.mq.sampler.MQSampler
line number         : 65
------------------------------- : uk.co.logtailer.jmeter.protocol.mq.sampler.MQSampler : uk.co.logtailer.jmeter.protocol.mq.sampler.MQSampler
```

Comment: So what did the log file say?

Comment: Added the logs in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have the jar, containing `uk.co.logtailer.jmeter.protocol.mq.sampler.MQSampler` and `uk.co.logtailer.jmeter.protocol.mq.control.gui.MQSamplerGui` classes in your JMeter's classpath. You need to find it somewhere and drop it to lib/ext folder of your JMeter installation.

However looking into `enabled="false"` stanza, if all these custom samplers are disabled you can safely (and carefully) remove them from .jmx file via any text editor, preferably having XML syntax highlighting and XML validation capabilities.

A couple of guides on JMS/MQ testing with JMeter:

- [Building a JMS Topic Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-topic-test-plan.html)
- [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. But there are some which are enabled so I need the JAR.